# Restore to SQL Server 6.5 and Migrate to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a database backup file from SQL Server 6.5. The file size is 52GB.

How can I restore this database file?

How can I migrate it to SQL Server 2014?

Comment: I`m not sure but you`ll need to upgrade it in stages, from 6.5 to to the highest compatible version and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have access to a backup file, to do this without using any third party tools (if even are any) requires you to move from version to version, which of course means that you have to have access to servers running three different versions, and unless you have the installation media at least SQL Server 2000 will probably be hard to get hold on.

If you have access to the server from where the backup originated you might be better off trying to export the data to some format that later versions can use.

If you choose the *restore backup* route a path that should work is this:

```
6.5 -> 2000 
2000 (sp4) -> 2008
2008 -> 2014
```

A couple relevant of TechNet articles:

[Migration SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012.aspx)

[Copying Databases from SQL Server 7.0 or Earlier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177398%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

There might be other and potentially better ways to do this, and I would consider asking this on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If my answer is factually incorrect would the down voter please let me know so that I can revise it? If not, then why the down vote?

Comment: Thanks, my database backup file size is 52GB (SQL Server 6.5) and i can't restore it, how can i do it. I create 4 device with 20GB; 1. dev1, dev2, dev3, devLog. how can i restore 52GB file?

Comment: @user3840145 If you can't restore it I don't think there's much else you can do. I'm not aware of any other way to get a 6.5 backup to later versions. Why is it you can't restore it?

Comment: I know, i have to create 4 device with 20GB; 1. dev1, dev2, dev3, devLog. then create datebase file, when i create db with dev1 and devLog, Much time remains in the loaded state does not change!!

Answer (score -3):

check the directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA) on your computer and copy the your database files of the older sql server system,for example if your databaase name is(test) you will copy the files test.ldf and test.mdf then go to the sql server system (2014)
to the same directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA) and paste youur files, after that open your sql server management studio and right click on ( Databases )
then select attach then click add to browse to your database files and select test.mdf and press ok

Comment: The directory you refer to is specific to the 2008R2 version, and the OP clearly states that his backup is from a version 6.5 server which can't be attached in any case.

Comment: try to attach it first to lower version like 2010 or 2012 then copy it to 2014

Comment: The database format in 6.5 is different and incompatible with any version later than 2000 so attaching isn't an option. Also there there never was any 2010 version...